# How can I solve this maximization problem with inequality constraint on the Frobenius norm?

Tags: matrices, optimization, qclp

$$
\max_{C\in \mathbb{S}^n} x^TCx\\
s.t. \|C\|_{tr}^2\leq b
$$
where $\|C\|_{tr}^2=tr(C^TC)=tr(CC)$, $C$ is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: What is the norm used  to define the unit sphere on symmetric matrices ? Is $x$ fixed ?

Comment: $x$ is fixed, and the norm is Frobenius norm which $\|C\|_{tr}^2=\|C\|_F^2=tr(CC^T)=tr(CC)$

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing slightly, given vector ${\rm a} \in \Bbb R^n \setminus \{ \Bbb 0_n \}$ and scalar $b >0$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & {\rm a}^\top {\rm X} \, {\rm a}\\ \text{subject to} & \| {\rm X} \|_{\text{F}} \leq b\end{array}$$

Using the cyclic property of the trace, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and $\| {\rm a} {\rm a}^\top \|_{\text{F}} = \| {\rm a} \|_2^2$,

$${\rm a}^\top {\rm X} \, {\rm a} = \mbox{tr} \left( {\rm a}^\top {\rm X} \, {\rm a} \right) = \mbox{tr} \left( {\rm a} {\rm a}^\top {\rm X} \right) = \langle {\rm a} {\rm a}^\top, {\rm X} \rangle \leq \| {\rm a} {\rm a}^\top \|_{\text{F}} \underbrace{\| {\rm X} \|_{\text{F}}}_{\leq b} \leq b \| {\rm a} \|_2^2$$

where the maximum is attained at

$$\bar{{\rm X}} := b \underbrace{\frac{{\rm a} {\rm a}^\top}{\,\,\,\| {\rm a} {\rm a}^\top \|_{\text{F}}}}_{=: {\rm P}_{\rm a}} = b \left( \frac{{\rm a}}{\,\,\,\| {\rm a} \|_2} \right) \left( \frac{{\rm a}}{\,\,\,\| {\rm a} \|_2} \right)^\top = b \, {\rm P}_{\rm a}$$

where ${\rm P}_{\rm a}$ is a rank-$1$ projection matrix.

Comment: Thanks! Your method is better than mine! Nice slack steps~

Comment: If you don't want to use the cyclic property of the trace, just use Cauchy- Schwarz, the operator norm and that Frobenius is an upper bound for the spectral norm.

Answer (score 0):

Through some calculations, I have an idea as follows:
$$
L=x^TCx-\lambda(\|C\|_{tr}^2-b)
$$
Calculating $\frac{\partial L}{\partial C}$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial C}=xx^T=\lambda C\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}=tr(CC^T)=b
$$
that is
$$
C=\frac{xx^T}{\lambda}
$$
plugging the term into the second equation, we have
$$
tr(xx^T/\lambda)=\sqrt{b}\\
tr(xx^T/\lambda)=1=\sum{x_i^2}/\lambda\\
\lambda = \|x\|^2=\sum{x_i^2}
$$
Hence, the solution is
$$
C^*=\sqrt{b}*\frac{xx^T}{\|x\|^2}
$$

Comment: Doubtful. If $b\geq 1$, then your second constraint is automatically satisfied and the answer should only depend on $x$ in this case...

Comment: Why automatically satisfied? According to the definition of $\|\cdot\|_{tr}^2$, and let $C=\mathbb{I}_{2\times 2}, b=3$, we have $b>\|CC^t\|_{tr}^2=2>1$

Comment: I meant: if $b\geq 1$ and $C\in S^n$, your second constraint is automatically satisfied. Your example is a nonexample: the identity matrix does not lie in $S^n$.

Comment: $\mathcal{S}^n$ is the collection of symmetric matrixes, why identity matrix does not lie in $\mathcal{S}^n$?

Comment: The notation you used is the standard notation for the unit sphere. You should change it or precise the signification in your post.